# MySQL MAX_JOIN_SIZE error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is a call history table which logs calls made (starttime, endtime, phone number, user, etc). The other is an orders table which logs order details (order number, customer info, orderdate, etc.). Orders are not always created when a call is created so there isnt a guaranteed ID to match them up. Right now, I'm interested in getting totals by day. When I try to run a a query to sum calls and join orders by day I get the following error:

```
The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    COUNT(c.id) as calls,
    COUNT(o.id) as orders

FROM tbl_calls c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_orders o 
    ON DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')  =  DATE_FORMAT(o.created,'%Y-%m-%d') 

WHERE c.campaign_id = 1 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-12-09'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Even when there are only a few calls for a particular day, it still shows the same error. So I'm pretty sure it my query that needs work.

I have also tried a sub query, but that doesn't rollup the totals from the subquery.

```
SELECT

    DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    count(c.id) as calls,
    (select count(DISTINCT o.id)
                    FROM tbl_orders o
                    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(o.created,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')
                ) as orders

FROM tb_calls c

WHERE c.campaign_id = 1 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2013-12-09' AND '2013-12-15'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')
WITH ROLLUP
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this query to work? Ultimately I'd like a result like below so I can do other calculations like % orders etc.

```
date         |  calls   |    orders
------------------------------------
2013-12-01   |       100|       10
2013-12-02   |       125|       20
NULL         |       225|       30
```

**UPDATED:**
Based on the answer I did the following:
created call_date field with  a date field (no datetime) to tbl_calls
created date_order field with a date format (not datetime) to tbl_orders
Updated each table and set the new fields to = date_format(the_date_time_stamp,'%Y-%m-%d') from the same table.
Also added an index to each of the new date fields.

That made the following query work:

```
SELECT
    c.call_date as date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as calls,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) as orders,
    ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.id))*100,2) as conversion

FROM tbl_calls c
 JOIN tbl_orders o 
    ON c.call_date  =  o.date_order

WHERE c.campaign_id = 1 
    AND c.call_date BETWEEN '2013-12-09' AND '2013-12-15' 

GROUP BY c.call_date
WITH ROLLUP
```

Which gives me the following result and I can build off of this. Thanks to each of you who provided suggestions. I tried each. All make sense. However, since I ultimately had to create the additional date fields I chose the answer by

```
date         | calls  | orders| conversion
-------------------------------------------
2013-12-09   |  151   | 6     | 3.97
2013-12-10   |  164   | 2     | 1.22
2013-12-11   |  165   | 6     | 3.64
2013-12-12   |  189   | 1     | 0.53
2013-12-13   |  116   | 4     | 3.45
null         |  785   | 19    | 2.42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - try the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT....` where `...` is the rest of your select query above.

Since you're performing the join on two fields which have a function applied to them - I'm take a guess and say MySQL is performing two full table scans and using type `all` for the join. See [this for an explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) of the `EXPLAIN` output.

```
DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')  =  DATE_FORMAT(o.created,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

You'll most likely want to create a separate field in each table that contains just the result of the DATE_FORMAT call. Then create an index for each of these new fields. Then join on these new indexed fields. MySQL should like that much better.

Comment: It's also possible that it might be able to optimize `DATE(c.date_call_start) = DATE(o.created)` because of the simple relationship between datetime and date.

Comment: I tried every suggestion. even @Barmar . Was soo hoping that would work, because it was the simplest, but it did not. :( So I did create two new fields with just dates. Then updated the table and set the new fields to equal the result of date_format().

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to count the calls and orders for each date.  However, that is not what your query does, because it creates a cartesian product for all orders on a given date.

Instead, summarize the data first by date and then combine the results.  This may be what you want:

```
select c.date, calls, orders
from (select DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, count(*) as calls
      from tbl_calls c
      WHERE c.campaign_id = 1 and
            DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-12-09'
      group by DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
     ) c left outer join
     (select DATE_FORMAT(o.created,'%Y-%m-%d') as date, count(*) as orders
      from tbl_orders o
      group by DATE_FORMAT(o.created, '%Y-%m-%d')
     ) o
     on c.date = o.date;
```

Comment: This works for the initial query, but I cannot expand it with ROLLUP. When I tried using the same logic and used UNION with a one line result, I could not get orders to add up. Very odd. However, if I added a date field (just date not datetime) to each table, and run your suggestions it all works fine (with the union for the summary row). Your suggesstion actually help me realize I can use a select for the FROM tables and JOIN them. Very Cool!

Comment: @dev7apps . . . You would just add `rollup` to the subqueries and fix the join condition to handle the `NULL` dates.

Answer (score 1):

If @Barmar 's suggestion does not work, then you may need to split the fields into DATE and TIME.

A different direction is to make two temp tables (giving you three queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tbl_calls_temp`  SELECT *  FROM tbl_calls c WHERE DATE(c.date_call_start) = '2013-12-09' AND c.campaign_id = 1
```

Then do the same restricting for the tbl_orders TABLE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tbl_orders_temp` SELECT * FROM tbl_orders o WHERE DATE(o.created) = '2013-12-09'
```

Finally query against the two temporary tables. Depending on how much data  you get, you may want to add indexes to the temporary tables... but in all likelihood you are facing a full-join

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    COUNT(c.id) as calls,
    COUNT(o.id) as orders

FROM tbl_calls_temp c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_orders_temp o 
    ON DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')  =  DATE_FORMAT(o.created,'%Y-%m-%d') 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.date_call_start,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

And that should be much faster... assuming you have any indexes in your initial tables that can be queried.

Comment: This makes sense. unfortunately I was unable to get the temp tables to work in my query. I keep getting a dbname.c.tbl_calls_temp doesn't exist. I assume I would call all three at the same time separating them with a semicolon, but no go.

Comment: you can do it without using TEMPORARY tables, but then you need to add a few queries. you need to DROP IF EXISTS ad the beginning before creating them and then drop them at the end again.